# PHP Split int into random values

Tags: php, random, int

I have a int called v_cnt which im using a maximum value for a voting system, them im using mt_rand to generate a random number of 'votes' (used for gaming purposes not a rigged system)

```
// vote 1
$vote_limit = $v_cnt;
$vote_1 = mt_rand(0, $vote_limit); 
// vote 2
$vote_limit = $v_cnt - $vote_1; if($vote_limit < 0){ $vote_limit = 0;}
$vote_2 = mt_rand(0, $vote_limit);
// vote 3
$vote_limit = $v_cnt - ($vote_1 + $vote_2); if($vote_limit < 0){ $vote_limit = 0;}
$vote_3 = mt_rand(0, $vote_limit);
```

This gives me vote_1, vote_2 and vote_3 which is ideal. But, since mt_rand is a random value up to the limit, im not getting quite the result i need as i need it to calculate like this;

(vote_1 + vote_2 + vote_3) = $v_cnt

So essentially i need to split an int into 3 random values which must add up to equal the starting number. I hope this makes sense.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have all three random. It's impossible.
The first two, sure. But the last one can only be one number and that is what is remaining.

```
// vote 1
$vote_limit = $v_cnt;
$vote_1 = mt_rand(0, $vote_limit); 
// vote 2
$vote_limit = $v_cnt - $vote_1; 
$vote_2 = mt_rand(0, $vote_limit);
// vote 3
$vote_3 = $v_cnt - ($vote_1 + $vote_2);
```

https://3v4l.org/2C2bu

Also I'm not sure what you expect this line to do: `if($vote_limit < 0){ $vote_limit = 0;}`.
$vote_limit can't be negative since you have a limit of the random number.

---

I see that you have added a request to have unique numbers.
I created a new code that outputs $n_votes votes that is all unique and none is negative and all in between 0 and $v_cnt.

```
$v_cnt = 100;
$n_votes = 3;

$numbers = range(0,$v_cnt); // create array of 0->100
shuffle($numbers); // shuffle the array
$votes = array_fill(0, $n_votes-1, 1); // create an array that will NOT exit loop below.
// Array_fill returns [1,1,1] which does not match the requirements so the loop starts

//Loop until all values in votes are unique and none is negative
while(count(array_unique($votes)) != $n_votes || $votes[$n_votes-1]<1){
    // Take two consecutive numbers of random place in the array
    $votes = array_slice($numbers, mt_rand(0, $v_cnt-$n_votes+1),$n_votes-1);
    // Count what the last item should be
    $votes[] = $v_cnt - array_sum($votes);
}
echo array_sum($votes) . "\n";
Var_dump($votes);
```

https://3v4l.org/2h7DB

Just as a fun thing to look at, if I include a $i in the code we can see how many tries in the loop was needed to create the unique array. https://3v4l.org/mPae5
Keep in mind this code is very sensitive to max limit opposed to number of votes.
If you have a relatively low $v_cnt and a high $n_votes it may never find the numbers needed.
Just try and set $n_votes to 5 in the latest link and you can see that $i number can be 100+ (meaning more than 100 loops was needed to get a correct set of numbers).

Comment: thank you, can't believe i just looked straight over that.

Comment: in response to your edit, looking at it again, you are right, i been so careful trying to catch values that will cause issues, that from a quick check i've done this a few times.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help, i appreciate your efforts. I will give your code a run soon and get back to you.

Comment: So after some testing it works exactly how i need. Thank you.

Comment: No problems! Again I can't say it enough, don't have to many votes on a small range of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

here is how I would handle this...

```
$vote_limit = $v_cnt;
$numbers_required = 3;

for($i=1;$i<=$numbers_required;$i++)
{

    if($i != $numbers_required)
    {

        $votes[$i] = mt_rand(0, $vote_limit);
        $vote_limit -= $votes[$i];

    } else {

        $votes[$numbers_required] = $v_cnt - array_sum($votes);

    }

}

echo $votes[1]; // First
echo $votes[2]; // Second
echo $votes[3]; // Third
```

Comment: I like this improved method, but could you explain this line to me please $v_cnt = $vote_limit = 100;

Comment: Sorry, that was just when I was testing for you. I have updated my answer to remove that.

Comment: thats no problem,do you know a way to make each number different, i always need a majority or winning vote so for example couldnt have 20, 20, 10, where as 21, 20, 9 would be fine.

Comment: hmmm, that adds a small bit of complexity but perhaps on the first call to `mt_rand($min, $max)` set the `$min` to be the `ceil($vote_limit/2)` something like that... have fun!

Comment: You should include some comments or a description of what your code does differently from OPs. Just dumping code is not an appropriate way to answer a question.

Comment: @Andreas - thats funny you should say that when your original answer had just about the same amount of inline comments as mine does - then you go and edit your own answer to add comments. Get out of here.

Comment: I did not say inline comments. I said comments **or description** my description has been there all time. The reason I included I line comments to the second answer is because it is much more advanced than OPs original question